# How to change the DataContractSerializer text encoding?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization, character-encoding

When writing to a stream the `DataContractSerializer` uses an encoding different from Unicode-16. If I could force it to write/read Unicode-16 I could store it in a SQL CE's `binary` column and read it with `SELECT CONVERT(nchar(1000), columnName)`. But the way it is, I can't read it, except programatically.

Can I change the encoding used by `System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer`?

Comment: This link might help you: http://sedodream.com/CategoryView,category,DataContractSerializer.aspx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The DataContractSerializer's `WriteObject` method has overloads which write to a `Stream` or to a `XmlWriter` (and `XmlDictionaryWriter`). The `Stream` overload will default to UTF-8, so you'll need to use another one. Using a XML Writer instance which writes the XML in UTF-16 do what you needs, so you can either do what @Phil suggested, or you can use the writer returned by `XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter` for which you pass an `Encoding.Unicode` as a parameter.

```
public class StackOverflow_10089682
{
    [DataContract(Name = "Person", Namespace = "http://my.namespace")]
    public class Person
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        XmlDictionaryWriter writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(ms, Encoding.Unicode);
        DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Person));
        Person instance = new Person { Name = "John Doe", Age = 33 };
        dcs.WriteObject(writer, instance);
        writer.Flush(); // Don't forget to Flush the writer here
        Console.WriteLine("Decoding using UTF-16: {0}", Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Undisposed objects - not nice.

Comment: Sure, it needs cleaning up. But I'd rather keep the code as small as possible to focus on what the question is (how to use a different encoding for writing) while still complete enough that it can be run by itself.

Comment: This does not write the XML declaration. If you want this, use XmlTextWriter, as in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10089892/2279059

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using XmlWriterSettings?  Something like

```
var s = new DataContractSerializer (typeof(Thing));

using(var wr = XmlTextWriter.Create(
    @"test.xml", new XmlWriterSettings{Encoding=Encoding.UTF32}))
{
    s.WriteObject(wr, new Thing{Foo="bar"});
}

public class Thing
{   
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Specify the Encoding you require.

Comment: DataContractSerializer won't write to a XmlTextWriter. It compiles, but nothing is written.

Comment: It works Ok for me.  Quick test in LINQPad with Encoding.Unicode gives <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><UserQuery.Thing xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/"><Foo>bar</Foo></UserQuery.Thing>

Comment: Try supplying a full path, not just 'test.xml', so you're know where the output is ending up.

Comment: Where you using a 'using' statement?  You'll find that disposing the text writer also flushes it.

Comment: Yes, I used it. No, it didn't.